# Ionic2 selcted value undefined

Tags: ionic2

Hi I have a select box in ionic 2 as.

```
//home.html

      <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Select City</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="city"  (ionChange) ="getDoors()">
      <ion-option  *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
       {{city.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

//home.ts
getDoors(){
 console.log(this.cities);
}
```

[image]

But when I am changing option it throw an error, Error trying to diff '1'

can anyone let me know the issue here

Thanks advance

Comment: Your code is working well for me, how are you getting `this.cities`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 methods through which you can get the value of the selected Item.

**Method 1**

//home.html

```
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select City</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="city"  (ionChange) ="getDoors($event)">
  <ion-option  *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
   {{city.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>

//home.ts
getDoors($event){
 console.log($event);
}
```

**Method 2**

By using **ngModel**

```
 //home.html

  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select City</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedcity"  (ionChange) ="getDoors($event)">
  <ion-option  *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
   {{city.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>

//home.ts
selectedcity: city
getSelectedCity(){
 return this.selectedcity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you named your ngModel city and your *ngFor uses city as well. Might cause a conflict. I would change your ngModel to

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
```